# How to get sub array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to get an array composed of the first `4` rows of the original array `$arr`,

how to do it in PHP?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

[array_slice()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

```
$subArray = array_slice($arr,0,4);
```

Comment: What if I don't know the offset ?

Comment: @JCharette - then you need to identify the offset, using functions like `array_search()`  perhaps.... but that would depend entirely on what you needed to do, and is an entirely different question

Comment: it resets the keys, not worked for me. Thanks

Comment: `$output = array_slice($arr, 0, 1, true);` solved my issue and preserves the keys also. Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

You need to use [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php).

```
$output = array_slice($arr, 0, 4);
```

Comment: it resets the keys, not worked for me. Thanks

Comment: `$output = array_slice($arr, 0, 1, true);` solved my issue and preserves the keys also. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Check this out.. this should help

```
<?php
$input = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");

$output = array_slice($input, 2);      // returns "c", "d", and "e"
$output = array_slice($input, -2, 1);  // returns "d"
$output = array_slice($input, 0, 3);   // returns "a", "b", and "c"

// note the differences in the array keys
print_r(array_slice($input, 2, -1));
print_r(array_slice($input, 2, -1, true));
?>
```

From http://docs.php.net/array_slice.

Comment: When posting code from another source, you should always paste the link in too.