# Slice an associate array arround the particular position

Tags: php, arrays

I have an associate array with large number of data. I need to slice it in simple way without iterating through the array. I need to slice array from **(n-d)** th position element to **(n+d)** th position element.as example below,

```
$arr= array(
    'a'=>1,
    'b'=>2,
    'c'=>3,
    'd'=>4,
    'e'=>5,
    'f'=>6,
    'g'=>7,
    'h'=>8,
    'i'=>9,
    'j'=>10,
     11,
     12,
     13
);
```

> n= 5 and d = 3,

output should be

```
[3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

I can do this iterating through the array. If you have any idea to slice array by getting **n** and **d** parameters. please help me.

Thank You

Comment: answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927752/how-to-get-sub-array-in-php

Comment: How can you duplicate this